# Loading images from models with jinja templating

Tags: python, django, jinja2

I have a simple blog, and an image in my articles model that I'd like to use as a background image in a div on my website. The image doesn't load the way the code is written now.

I've tried changing the media and static settings in my settings.py, but I'm not sure if this is what the issue is.

here is my articles model.

```py
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    overview = models.TextField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField()
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    featured = models.BooleanField()
    content = HTMLField(null=True)
    is_draft = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('article-detail', kwargs={
            'id': self.id
        })
```

here is the index.html page, an example of how I'm trying to call the image now using jinja tags:

```py
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}


        <section data-overlay>
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row mb-4">

              <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-9">
                {% for post in queryset %}
                <div class="pr-lg-4">
                  <a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}" class="bg-primary-3-alt rounded p-4 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center min-vh-20">
                    <img src="{{ article.thumbnail.url }}" alt="Avatar" class="avatar mr-2">
                    <span class="text-small text-primary-3">{{ post.title }}</span>
                  </a>
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
                <br>
                <div class="row justify-content-center pr-lg-4">
                  <div class="col-auto">
                    <nav>
                      <ul class="pagination mb-0">
                        {% if queryset.has_previous %}
                        <li class="page-item"><a href="?{{ page_request_var }}={{ queryset.previous_page_number }}" class="page-link">Previous</a></li>
                        {% endif %}
                        <li class="page-item"><a href="?{{ page_request_var }}={{ queryset.number }}" class="page-link active"> {{ queryset.number }}</a></li>
                        {% if queryset.has_next %}
                        <li class="page-item"><a href="?{{ page_request_var }}={{ queryset.next_page_number }}" class="page-link">Next</a></li>
                        {% endif %}
                      </ul>
                    </nav>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-3 d-none d-md-block">
                <div class="mb-4">
                  <h5>Newsletter</h5>
                  <form action="/forms/mailchimp.php" data-form-email novalidate>
                    <div class="form-row">
                      <div class="col-12">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control mb-2" placeholder="Email Address" name="email" required>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-12">
                        <div class="d-none alert alert-success" role="alert" data-success-message>
                          Thanks, a member of our team will be in touch shortly.
                        </div>
                        <div class="d-none alert alert-danger" role="alert" data-error-message>
                          Please fill all fields correctly.
                        </div>
                        <div data-recaptcha data-sitekey="INSERT_YOUR_RECAPTCHA_V2_SITEKEY_HERE" data-size="invisible" data-badge="bottomleft">
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-loading btn-block" data-loading-text="Sending">
                          <svg class="icon" width="24px" height="24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
                            <title>Icon For Loading</title>
                            <g stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
                              <g>
                                <polygon points="0 0 24 0 24 24 0 24" opacity="0"></polygon>
                              </g>
                              <path d="M12,4 L12,6 C8.6862915,6 6,8.6862915 6,12 C6,15.3137085 8.6862915,18 12,18 C15.3137085,18 18,15.3137085 18,12 C18,10.9603196 17.7360885,9.96126435 17.2402578,9.07513926 L18.9856052,8.09853149 C19.6473536,9.28117708 20,10.6161442 20,12 C20,16.418278 16.418278,20 12,20 C7.581722,20 4,16.418278 4,12 C4,7.581722 7.581722,4 12,4 Z"
                              fill="#000000" fill-rule="nonzero" transform="translate(12.000000, 12.000000) scale(-1, 1) translate(-12.000000, -12.000000) "></path>
                            </g>
                          </svg>
                          <span>Subscribe</span>
                        </button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </form>
                  <small class="text-muted form-text">We’ll never share your details. See our <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a>
                  </small>

                </div>
                <div class="mb-4">
                  <h5>Popular</h5>
                  <ul class="list-unstyled list-articles">
                    <li class="row row-tight">
                      <a href="#" class="col-3">
                        <img src="img/article-1.jpg" alt="Image" class="rounded">
                      </a>
                      <div class="col">
                        <a href="#">
                          <h6 class="mb-1">How to build collateral</h6>
                        </a>
                        <div class="d-flex text-small">
                          <a href="#">Business</a>
                          <span class="text-muted ml-1">29th November</span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>

{% endblock %}
```

Here are my views.py for my index.html

```py
def index(request):
    article_list = Article.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(article_list, 4)
    page_request_var = 'page'
    page = request.GET.get(page_request_var)
    try:
        paginated_queryset = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        paginated_queryset = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        paginated_queryset = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    context = {
        'queryset': paginated_queryset,
        'page_request_var': page_request_var,
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

And here are my urls.py

```py
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from articles.models import Author, Article, Category
from articles.views import home, article, index

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),
    path('', home),
    path('index', index, name='article-list'),
    path('article/<id>/', article, name='article-detail'),
    path('about',TemplateView.as_view(template_name="about.html"), name = 'about'),
    path('contact',TemplateView.as_view(template_name="contact.html"), name = 'contact'),
    path('article', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="article.html"), name='article'),
]
```

Everything in the site is running fine, I just don't get any images loaded. Instead, I get the the broken image tag and whatever alt text I put.

Comment: When you inspect the **img** tag, what value do you see for **src**?

Comment: @mbhargav294 I get media url for the img ("/media/imagename.jpg")

Comment: What makes you think you are using Jinja2 here?

Comment: if you open the url directly are you able to see the image? eg: localhost:8080/media/imagename.jpg. If yes, what happens when you hardcode the domain name within the src attribute?

Comment: @mbhargav294 no, I'm not able to see the image

Comment: Huh! How are you uploading the image into your ImageField? You need to provide a MEDIA_ROOT in your settings and any image added in the ImageField will be uploaded to this MEDIA_ROOT and the relative path to this file will be stored in the database. See here for more information: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.storage

Comment: @mbhargav294 media_root and url is in settings, so not sure what the issue is.